# What would be the Functor instance for the following type: newtype F2 x a = F2 ((a -> x) -> a)

Tags: haskell, functor

So I want to write the fmap function for the above mentioned type, but I am stuck here:

```
instance Functor (F2 x) where
 fmap :: (a -> b) -> (F2 x a) -> (F2 x b)
 fmap f (F2 g) = F2 ( f _ )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good strategy here is to follow the types. GHC can help us along the way if we write incomplete definitions with [typed holes](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#typed-holes):

```
newtype F2 x a = F2 ((a -> x) -> a)

instance Functor (F2 x) where
    fmap f (F2 g) = _
```

If we try to compile this, GHC reports back:

```
Diatonic.hs:275:21: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: F2 x b
      Where: ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> F2 x a -> F2 x b
               at Diatonic.hs:275:5-8
             ‘x’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the instance declaration
               at Diatonic.hs:274:10-23
    • In the expression: _
      In an equation for ‘fmap’: fmap f (F2 g) = _
      In the instance declaration for ‘Functor (F2 x)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        g :: (a -> x) -> a (bound at Diatonic.hs:275:16)
        f :: a -> b (bound at Diatonic.hs:275:10)
        fmap :: (a -> b) -> F2 x a -> F2 x b (bound at Diatonic.hs:275:5)
    |
275 |     fmap f (F2 g) = _
    |
```

This means we have to fill the hole with an `F2 x b` value. The only way we have of creating one is by using the constructor (for the following steps, I will omit the unchanging boilerplate):

```
fmap f (F2 g) = F2 _
```

```
• Found hole: _ :: (b -> x) -> b
```

So we need a function that takes a `b -> x`. We can set up one. Let's call its argument `k`, and see if we can complete its body:

```
fmap f (F2 g) = F2 (\k -> _)
```

```
• Found hole: _ :: b
```

The only thing that can produce a `b` is `f :: a -> b`:

```
fmap f (F2 g) = F2 (\k -> f _)
```

```
• Found hole: _ :: a
```

The only thing that can produce an `a` is `g :: (a -> x) -> a`:

```
fmap f (F2 g) = F2 (\k -> f (g _))
```

```
• Found hole: _ :: a -> x
```

We are supposed to provide an `a -> x` function, so let's throw in another lambda (for a possible shortcut, see the final part of the answer):

```
fmap f (F2 g) = F2 (\k -> f (g (\a -> _)))
```

```
• Found hole: _ :: x
```

The only thing that can produce a `x` is `k :: b -> x`

```
fmap f (F2 g) = F2 (\k -> f (g (\a -> k _)))
```

```
• Found hole: _ :: b
```

The only thing that can produce a `b` still is `f :: a -> b`:

```
fmap f (F2 g) = F2 (\k -> f (g (\a -> k (f _))))
```

```
• Found hole: _ :: a
```

If we try to use `g` to create an `a` value like we did several steps ago, we will get trapped in a vicious circle. However, we don't have to do that this time, as the `a` argument of the lambda is in scope:

```
fmap f (F2 g) = F2 (\k -> f (g (\a -> k (f a))))
```

And we are done.

(It is worth mentioning that your `F2` is provided by *transformers*, [where it is known as `Select`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Select.html).)

The definition arguably looks a little tidier if we write `\a -> k (f a)` pointfree:

```
instance Functor (F2 x) where
    fmap f (F2 g) = F2 (\k -> f (g (k . f)))
```

We might have skipped directly from the `a -> x` hole to here by noticing our only viable option there was composing `f :: a -> b` and `k :: b -> x`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make GHC do the hard work for you:

```
GHCi, version 8.8.2: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set -ddump-deriv -dsuppress-all -XDeriveFunctor
Prelude> newtype F2 x a = F2 ((a -> x) -> a) deriving(Functor)

==================== Derived instances ====================
Derived class instances:
  instance Functor (F2 x) where
    fmap f_a1bk (F2 a1_a1bl)
      = F2
          ((\ b4_a1bm b5_a1bn
              -> f_a1bk
                   (b4_a1bm
                      ((\ b2_a1bo b3_a1bp
                          -> (\ b1_a1bq -> b1_a1bq) (b2_a1bo (f_a1bk b3_a1bp)))
                         b5_a1bn)))
             a1_a1bl)
    (<$) z_a1br (F2 a1_a1bs)
      = F2
          ((\ b6_a1bt b7_a1bu
              -> (\ b5_a1bv -> z_a1br)
                   (b6_a1bt
                      ((\ b3_a1bw b4_a1bx
                          -> (\ b2_a1by -> b2_a1by)
                               (b3_a1bw ((\ b1_a1bz -> z_a1br) b4_a1bx)))
                         b7_a1bu)))
             a1_a1bs)


Derived type family instances:


Prelude>
```

Rename GHC's weird names and remove its excessive indentation, and you end up with this:

```
instance Functor (F2 x) where
  fmap f (F2 a1) = F2 ((\b4 b5 -> f (b4 ((\b2 b3 -> (\b1 -> b1) (b2 (f b3))) b5))) a1)
```

Now we can do some simplification to make that more understandable. Let's look at this subexpression:

```
(\b2 b3 -> (\b1 -> b1) (b2 (f b3))) b5
```

`(\b1 -> b1)` is the identity function, which we can beta-reduce to get rid of:

```
(\b2 b3 -> b2 (f b3)) b5
```

Now we can beta-reduce again, this time `b5` for `b2`:

```
\b3 -> b5 (f b3)
```

This is now clearly equivalent to `b5 . f`. Plug it back in:

```
instance Functor (F2 x) where
  fmap f (F2 a1) = F2 ((\b4 b5 -> f (b4 (b5 . f))) a1)
```

One more beta-reduction: `a1` for `b4`:

```
instance Functor (F2 x) where
  fmap f (F2 a1) = F2 (\b5 -> f (a1 (b5 . f)))
```

And we're done! No hard work on our part needed.

Comment: In this case, `-O -ddump-simpl` will surely give better results. The deriving mechanism relies on the simplifier to remove some of its cruft. The only challenge will be finding the mess that the `Functor` instance turns into.

Comment: @dfeuer That results in ``$cfmap = \ @ x @ a @ b f ds b5 -> f ((ds `cast` <Co:3>) (\ b3 -> b5 (f b3)))``. I feel like there's another challenge: explaining what ``(`cast` <Co:3>)`` is and how it made the wrapper type go away (and what's with all the @ signs).

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's an issue. You could use a datatype instead of a newtype to get rid of the casts, and add `-dsuppress-type-applications` or even `-dsuppress-all`, but I guess it's not as straightforward as I imagined.

Comment: @dfeuer `-dsuppress-all -dsuppress-uniques -dsuppress-type-applications -XDeriveFunctor -ddump-simpl -O` and `data` instead of `newtype` gives me `$fFunctorF2_$cfmap = \ @ x @ a @ b w w1 -> case w1 of { F2 ww1 -> F2 (\ b5 -> w (ww1 (\ b3 -> b5 (w b3)))) }`, which is definitely better, but still not great. In particular, I don't know why the `@`s are still there, and at least `case` is easier to explain than `cast`.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress type abstractions as well as applications?

Comment: You have to watch out with suppressing uniques, unfortunately. That can definitely turn code into garbage sometimes.

Comment: @dfeuer Yeah, I've learned the hard way about uniques before. Luckily it didn't mess up this case. Idle thought: I wish GHC could be smarter and only add suffixes when it needed to, instead of all the time. As for type abstractions, I'm not sure, but I'm guessing no since even `-dsuppress-all` didn't.